# A problem with notation

Tags: analysis, notation, fourier-transform, statistical-mechanics

I refer to the following paper:
[Reflection Positivity and Phase Transitions in Lattice Spin Models](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Ebiskup/PDFs/papers/Biskup-Prague-notes.pdf)

Denote $\mathbb{T}_L$ as the discrete torus.

My problem is the following, in page $19$ expression $(3.18)$, the author defines the function $G_L(x,y)$ which is a certain type o Discrete Fourier Transform, taking two values $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}^d$ and gives a complex value.

Later, in page $42$, expression $(5.26)$, the author computes $G^{-1}_L(\eta)$,
and $G_L(\eta)$, where $\eta \in (\mathbb{R}^\nu)^{\mathbb{T}_L}$.

I do not understand what value is referred to by those expressions ($G_L(\eta)$ and $G^{-1}_L(\eta))$. I suppose is some kind of common notation that I am not familiarized with.

Comment: Are you interested in ${\mathbb{R}^\nu}^\mathbb{T}_L$?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, my problem is with the notation $G_L(\eta)$ and $G^{-1}_L(\eta)$

Comment: I assume you've looked where the author defines the notation of their text

Comment: Equation 6.2 of this : http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~rauch/555/fouriercomplex.pdf might be what you're looking for.

Comment: It doesn't seen to be the case, the main problem it is that the function is $G_L$ was originally defined for coordinates in the discrete space and now we are trying to give a notion to $G_L$ as a function of a vector where each entry is a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{T}_L = \mathbb{Z}^d/L\mathbb{Z}^d$ denote the torus of side $L$. Although $G_L$ is defined as a matrix indexed by $\mathbb{T}_L$ (i.e. a map $G_L : \mathbb{T}_L \times \mathbb{T}_L \to \mathbb{R}$), we can view it (like any finite matrix) as a linear map $G_L : (\mathbb{R}^\nu)^{\mathbb{T}_L} \to (\mathbb{R}^\nu)^{\mathbb{T}_L}$. Precisely, for $\eta \in (\mathbb{R}^\nu)^{\mathbb{T}_L}$, the entries $(G_L \eta)^i_x$ of $G_L \eta \in (\mathbb{R}^\nu)^{\mathbb{T}_L}$ are given by (componentwise) matrix multiplication:
$$(G_L \eta)^i_x = \sum_{y\in\mathbb{T}_L} G_L(x, y) \eta^i_y, \qquad x \in \mathbb{T}_L, \quad i = 1, \ldots, \nu.$$
On the right-hand side, $G_L$ is being used as in (3.18). On the left-hand side, it is being used as in (5.26), where $G_L^{-1}$ is used to denote the inverse map to $G_L$ (when well-defined).